# Sol staking question

Tags: staking, sol, authority

When viewing my staking account it appears that my authority address has changed and my main address is no longer it
How do I change the authority back to my main address and is my main address still the owner of the staked account? Or was I scammed or hacked somehow?
Thank you in advance for response

Answer (score 1):

If your `stake authority` has changed and you are sure you did not make the change, something suspicious is happening. You should check the blockchain history as any change to the stake account appears there.

`stake authority` and `withdraw authority` control the `stake account`, with the `withdraw authority` being more important as it can withdraw the tokens. Very often these two authorities are the same because users configure it this way for simplicity.

Copy pasted from the Solana [documentation](https://docs.solana.com/staking/stake-accounts) on the topic:

```
Each stake account has two signing authorities specified by their respective address, each of which is authorized to perform certain operations on the stake account.

The stake authority is used to sign transactions for the following operations:

    Delegating stake
    Deactivating the stake delegation
    Splitting the stake account, creating a new stake account with a portion of the funds in the first account
    Merging two stake accounts into one
    Setting a new stake authority

The withdraw authority signs transactions for the following:

    Withdrawing un-delegated stake into a wallet address
    Setting a new withdraw authority
    Setting a new stake authority

The stake authority and withdraw authority are set when the stake account is created, and they can be changed to authorize a new signing address at any time. The stake and withdraw authority can be the same address or two different addresses.

The withdraw authority keypair holds more control over the account as it is needed to liquidate the tokens in the stake account, and can be used to reset the stake authority if the stake authority keypair becomes lost or compromised.
```

You can change the `stake authority` of a stake account, but you need the current `stake authority` to sign the transaction. [The command that can do this is here](https://docs.solana.com/cli/delegate-stake#set-stake-and-withdraw-authorities).

Comment: I've read up on the above but I'm lost when it speaks of the keypair I need I don't know how to access or view the current authorities keypair

Comment: Keypair is a technical way of working with SOL, your wallet is basically a UI for such keypairs. If you didn't use keypairs to handle your stake, then you'd have to check the documentation of whatever you used to stake those SOL, or ask a new question here specific to your wallet/method of staking. And if you're comfortable, share the stake account pubkey, it's easier for people to investigate.

Comment: Thank you pubkey to stake account. C8YUBP4Rj34qNsWZAviJcS49RHNoBpuqcR16q9FDQTN1  And used phantom wallet when staking

Comment: Yes, authority changed, don't know if this is a Phantom wallet feature or a malicious actor. The stake account in question was created and a few hours later the stake & withdraw authority was changed to the new one: `6GrdV2gSDEsWdghX158mDTNT4WoNcLkdeMb5sZZAVpmN`. Same account owns two more stake accounts, https://solanabeach.io/address/6GrdV2gSDEsWdghX158mDTNT4WoNcLkdeMb5sZZAVpmN/stakes

Answer (score 0):

The staking account is created with your wallet address as the signer. The authority is changed to the program address of the staking system to keep the funds safe/staked with it.

If you want to change the authority address back to your wallet address, you need to unstake & withdraw your Solana back to your account.

Comment: How do I unstake at this point tho it doesn't give me an option to do so

Comment: goto the same site where you staked and unstake your token, the smart contract underlying will change(if it exists)